# Double click required to output radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that output results based on radio button selection. The form has multiple radio buttons and based on the selection will show relevant div and hide the irrelevant ones.

In terms of functionality it works perfectly fine. The problem is that in order to output the result (once you have selected the radio button) **you have to press 2X the Submit button**.

Here is my code:

```js
(function($) {
  $('#quiz_submit').click(function() {

    $('#quiz_submit').click(function() {
      let checkedId = $('input[type=radio][name=quiz-selector]:checked').attr('id')
      if (checkedId == "option-one") {
        $('.a1').show();
        $('.a2, .a3').hide();
      } else if (checkedId == "option-two") {
        $('.a2').show();
        $('.a1, .a3').hide();
      } else if (checkedId == "option-three") {
        $('.a3').show();
        $('.a1, .a2').hide();
      }
    });


  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.re-quiz__internal {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.quiz__section {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  box-shadow: 10px 20px 36px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 40px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) !important;
}

.slider__section {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.type__quiz {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.quiz__title {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto 40px auto;
}

.quiz__form {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.quiz__item {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.quiz__item input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.quiz__item label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 25px 0px 25px 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

.quiz__item:hover label {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.quiz__item .check {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: border .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

.quiz__item:hover .check {
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.quiz__item .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: background 0.25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type=radio]:checked~.check {
  border: 4px solid #fff000;
}

input[type=radio]:checked~.check::before {
  background: #fff000;
}

input[type=radio]:checked~label {
  color: #EE78A5;
}

#quiz_submit {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #fff000;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 160px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.a1,
.a2,
.a3 {
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="re-quiz__internal">
  <div class="quiz__section">
    <p class="quiz__title">Questions for the quiz</p>
    <ul class="quiz__form">
      <li class="quiz__item">
        <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="quiz-selector">
        <label for="option-one">Qeustion number 1</label>
        <div class="check"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz__item">
        <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="quiz-selector">
        <label for="option-two">Qeustion number 2</label>

        <div class="check">
          <div class="inside"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz__item">
        <input type="radio" id="option-three" name="quiz-selector">
        <label for="option-three">Qeustion number 3</label>

        <div class="check">
          <div class="inside"></div>
        </div>
      </li>


    </ul>
    <input type="button" id="quiz_submit" class="submit-cta" value="SUBMIT">

    <!-- Answers -->
    <div class="a1">Answerof the questoon - One </div>
    <div class="a2">Answerof the questoon - Two </div>
    <div class="a3">Answerof the questoon - Three </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an event listener inside another, so the first one attach the 2nd one on the first click, and you only use the second one after that. Try this instead :

```
(function($) {
    $('#quiz_submit').click(function() {
      let checkedId = $('input[type=radio][name=quiz-selector]:checked').attr('id')
      if (checkedId == "option-one") {
        $('.a1').show();
        $('.a2, .a3').hide();
      } else if (checkedId == "option-two") {
        $('.a2').show();
        $('.a1, .a3').hide();
      } else if (checkedId == "option-three") {
        $('.a3').show();
        $('.a1, .a2').hide();
      }
    });
})(jQuery);
```